# Simulate async action in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following scenario: I'm loading and caching some data in order to avoid http requests for the same info, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it properly:

in the service:

```
this.get = function(id){
    var that = this,
    promise;

    if(that.loadedData){
        // resolve it right away if data is present
        promise = $q.defer();
        promise.resolve(that.loadedData);
        promise = promise.promise;
    }else{
        promise = $http.get('/get/'+id).then(function(response){
            that.loadedData = response;
        });
    }

    return promise
};
```

in the controller:

```
someService.get().then(function(){
    $scope.data = someService.loadedData;
});
```

Particularly the part where I'm manually creating a promise and resolving it right away "doesn't feel right", but it was the only way I found that worked. Is there some pattern for  dealing with scenarios like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is one.
AngularJS in `$http` has his own implementation of cache. Just set `cache` to **true** in its options:
Then firstly check data from cache, if not - ask backend.

```
this.get = function (id) {
    var cache = $cacheFactory('myCache'),
    that = this;
    this.loadedData = cache.get();

    if( !this.loadedData ) {
       return $http.get('/get/'+id, {cache: true}).then(function(response){
           that.loadedData = response;
       });
    }

    return $q.when( this.loadedData );
};
```

You need also return a promise from this method. That's why we wrapped `$q.when( this.loadedData )` and `$http` return promise by itself.
[Docs cacheFactory](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/ng.%24cacheFactory)

Answer (score 3):

Resolving right away is not a problem but I think it's a better practice that you return from the promise like:

```
this.get = function(id){
    var that = this;
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if(that.loadedData){
        // resolve it right away if data is present
        deferred.resolve(that.loadedData);
    }else{
        $http.get('/get/'+id).then(function(response){
            that.loadedData = response;
            deferred.resolve(response);
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

The point of using promise is to use it inside async function, which is in this case $http.get(). You will see a lot of this pattern in a lot of angular tutorials.

Comment: You probably dont want `promise = $http.get(...` there but rather just `$http.get(...` or you just made a global variable. I'm assuming that was just a typo but figured I'd point it out :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing seems like an awful amount of manual work. I'd recommend using Restangular:

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#can-i-cache-requests

But you can also achieve the same with pure angular. Take a looksie at:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24cacheFactory)

In most situations like this, I'd suggest using and trying to find existing solutions before attempting to solve the problem yourself. With that said, I also see nothing wrong with your approach apart from the fact that codewise looks yucky.